# How can I avoiding API Access alerts in WTK

Tags: java-me, emulation, java-wireless-toolkit, file-connection

I have made a Home - Made Nokia 5800 emulator in my WTK 2.5.1, by converting on of the WTK's devices.
In my program, i'm using FileConnection.
When a call made to this APi, an alert been displayed and block the screen. Since my "emulator" contains no buttons i can confim the access, and can not continue with debuging.
How can I remove this alert? I'm using NetBeans 6.9.1.
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing `JSR-75`. So its require permission to access that API for security reasons. Look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644067/fileconnection-problem-in-j2me-midp-2-0) and avoid security alerts on emulators. But for real time, you have to signing the application.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such alert in emulator.goto wirless toolkit select edit->preference->default emulator->security, set the security domain as maximum.
If in real device means u should get signed from the trusted party.