# Self-Signing J2me App

Tags: java-me, code-signing, self-signed

I have created a small j2me app (for personal use) for sending text messages.This j2me app fetches the messages
from my HTTP server and then send them to the fetched mobile number.
Now the Problem is that it asks for permission every time it send messages,
and as far as i know , i need to sign my app for permanent permission.
I don't want to buy the certificate just for my personal use. So i decide to self-sign 
my app.I followed this blog http://browndrf.blogspot.com/2006/06/build-and-install-singed-midlet.html
but unable to install .cer on my phone(Samsung GT-S5230).

I don't know if there is any eclipse plugin available for this.

Is there any other easy way to self-sign the j2me app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't go with self-signing for Java ME applications. Its not worth for MIDlet signing and also its not working most of the devices. So better option is buy it from some [third party providers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644067/fileconnection-problem-in-j2me-midp-2-0)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question