# How to set permissions of my j2me app to "Always allowed" on S40 devices?

Tags: security, java-me, permissions, midp, user-permissions

I have created an app in j2me, which runs fine with Nokia N8, C7 and other high-end devices. Now i am trying to port the same app to low-end devices S40 devices such as nokia 5130 express music. Every time my app runs, it asks, "Do you want the app to read user data?". Even in the application access -> Data access -> Read user data, only two options are active-

```
1. Ask every time and
2. Not allowed
```

and the other two options

```
3. Ask first time only and
4. Always allowed
```

are always inactive.
What shall i do to make these options active?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you will sign your app it doesn't guarantee that "Always allowed" will work, since there are 4 security domains:

1. Third party protection domain (untrusted 3rd party)
2. Identified third party protection domain (trusted 3rd party)
3. Operator protection domain
4. Manufacturer protection domain

If you're not operator like Verizon or manufacturer like Nokia, your maximum domain is 2nd and you can see and compare what you can do with this domain for S40 - [look here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/API_access_rights_on_phones,_Series_40_3rd_FP1)

You can also read this blog - [How MIDlet Signing is Killing J2ME](http://javablog.co.uk/2007/08/09/how-midlet-signing-is-killing-j2me/). Not very promising, heh?

Switch to Android or iPhone :) J2ME is outdated technology, don't waste your time.

Comment: barmaley, I accepted Java ME is outdated technology. But What do you think for Java ME supported mobiles? Java based mobiles still available. Its not dead in the market.

Comment: @bharath that's only reason why I'm still supporting several of my apps on JavaME, but I have stopped development of new products.

Comment: But If any requirements you need to develop this platform, right?

Comment: @bharath sure, if there'll be direct order - I will develop, but not as let's-develop-smth-and-we-will-see-probably-someone-will-buy

Answer (score 2):

You need to [sign your application.](http://www.joefission.com/2006/06/midp-application-signing/) Because you don't have [rights to access them.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/MIDP_2.0_API_access_rights)

Comment: Thanks bharath for the reply. When i do not sign the application, it runs(atleast) on the device. But when i sign the application using the "Built-in keystore" and trusted alias, it says "Certificate not on phone or sim". Do i need to manually install these certificates? Where do i get these certificates from? How to go about this?

Comment: No. You can't install the certificate manually. You need to sign from [some third party providers.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644067/fileconnection-problem-in-j2me-midp-2-0)

Comment: Also look on this article, [Java security domain on mobile.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_Security_Domains#Security_Domain_policies_for_a_number_of_carriers.2C_deviating_from_the_standard)